# Regular expression to retrieve text from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which will have values like

```
{ctrl1} + {ctrl2}
({ctrl1} / {ctrl2}) * {ctrl3}
if ({ctrl1} > {ctrl2}) then {ctrl1} * 10 else {ctrl} + {ctrl2} endif
```

there could be several formulas like this. This will be available in a string variable. I need extract all `{..}` values.

So, in example1, I should extract `{ctrl1}`, `{ctrl2}`. In Example2, I should extract `{ctrl1}`, `{ctrl2}`, `{ctrl3}`. In example3, I should extract `{ctrl1}`, `{ctrl2}`.

Can someone please help me with a regex for this?

Comment: What about `{ctrl}` in the last example?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like `{[^}]+}`.

Note however that that won't handle recursive stuff like `{hello{2}}`. You'll probably need an actual parser for things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `{\S+?}` should do the trick.

Comment: Not sure about C#'s regex implementation, but that might catch `{ctrl1}+{ctrl2}`. Probably should use non-greedy matching or use `{[^}]+}`

Comment: @cha0site you are right it would match `{ctrl1}+{ctrl2}`. I don't see the reason for the downvoting though **it still provides a solution to the proposed question given the example data.**

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the down-voter. You really ought to add the `?` for non-greedy matching though, it would make your answer better.

Comment: @cha0site wasn't targeting you, just saying in general to whoever downvoted. I have updated my answer for non-greedy matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine regex and LINQ and do this:

```
Regex.Matches(input, "{.*?}").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct();
```

Assuming `{ctrl}` was a typo in the last example.

Answer (score -2):

```
private void TrimControlNames()
    {
        if (txtFormula.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            string formula = txtFormula.Text.Trim();

            string pattern1 = "{[a-zA-Z0-9$_ ]+}"; //to identify control placeholders
            StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(formula, pattern1))
            {
                if (m.Value.Contains(" "))
                {
                    string str = m.Value.Replace(" ", string.Empty); //It is ok to remove like this since control names are not allowed to have spaces.
                    formula = formula.Replace(m.Value, str);
                }

            }

            txtFormula.Text = formula;
        }

    }
```

This method performs what I expected.

Comment: Your method doesn't work. Why don't you use one of the answers you got?